# EF not creating LocalDB in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started a simple MVC website and only added one model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyOwnWebsiteASP4dot6.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class GameDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added a controller and binded it to this model.

I expected the LocalDB to be created, but instead I get an error when I try to access the following method from my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Games.ToList());
}
```

My connection string:

```
 <add name="GameDBContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Games.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.\r\n)"}
```

Windows event log message:

```
The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key: {FB8B9694-6CD0-43DA-A73D-2727FC15C32A}
```

Comment: In your solution explorer window, click show all files and then expand data folder. Is there database file in it?

Comment: @Rusty: Nope, I already check it. It simply did not create it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have given different name to the connection string, I believe you will need to specify your connection string name while establishing connection.

```
public class GameDBContext: DbContext
{
    public GameDBContext()
      : base("GameDBContext")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that LocalDB was not installed. The way I found out, was simply restarting the Visual Studio project, which then tells you it is not installed and provides you directions on how to install it. Sadly I first did research, debugging and updates of VS before I actually ran it. At least now I know to restart the project first!